# Not finitely generated vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

I got the definition and the intuition being finitely generated vector spaces.
Could you help me with some examples about not finitely generated vector spaces?
It looks like  I can't get the intuition behind them.
Thank you in advance

Comment: For example, consider the space of all polynomial with real coefficients, where the polynomials are the vectors and the set of real numbers is the field of scalars. Equivalently, consider the space of of infinite sequences $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ of real numbers.

Comment: Another example: The set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As far as intuition, the vector space axioms don't require the space to be finitely generated, so these non-finitely-generated vector spaces are perfectly good vector spaces, but have infinite subsets which are linearly independent.

Comment: So , if I understood correctly , the key point is that we would have a base of infinite elements , which we cannot define?

Comment: @xNJL In some cases (e.g., polynomials) we can explicitely write down a base, in others (e.g. continuous functions) we can't. A notorious case where we really can't explicitly describe a basis is when vieweing $\Bbb R$ as (infinite-dimensional) vector space over the field $\Bbb Q$.